# Using RocksDB instead of HashMap in Spring Boot project, what pitfalls should be avoided?

Tags: java, database, performance, refactoring, rocksdb

#### Background:

There is a Spring Boot service that needs to **synchronize some data** from Elasticsearch to memory **during startup**. The processed data will be used by @Service A.
The data needs to be **synchronized regularly** from Elasticsearch.
Synchronizing the data during startup causes the service to **start too slowly**.

#### Ideas:

1. Can RocksDB be used as a replacement for HashMap as the synchronization target? This way, if the data does not change, it does not need to be synchronized repeatedly.
2. What should be noted when using this component?

[click to check process diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFJfA.png)

I didn't try it because I'm not very familiar with rocksdb. I've always been concerned about its read-write amplification problem.

Answer (score 1):

RocksDB is a persistent storage engine, so the functionality is a superset of what a HashMap can provide. The main disadvantage is performance. Read performance of RocksDB is likely to be worse than well-implemented HashMap. Some tuning can help performance if it runs on ramfs or working set is cached in DRAM, but it is still unlikely to match HashMap.

On the other hand, RocksDB does have some features that might allow users to load data to it much faster than HashMap. For example, https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Creating-and-Ingesting-SST-files allows users to load presorted data into RocksDB fast and without interrupting online reads. Another feature to RocksDB is that it can be stored, checkpointed or backed up in persistent storage, either on local disk or remote storage, so perhaps after restarts, it sometimes doesn't need to reload all the data. These features may or may not help your use case though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually, it is also possible not to use rocksdb. An urgent problem is how to speed up the service startup speed. Do not let the service load external storage data every time it starts, as this operation makes the service start too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Shared your question with the Speedb hive via Discord and here is the answer from Hilik, our Co-founder and Chief scientist:

We need more details about what is the hw topology etc. In general, if you use/have a common storage you can use rocksdb for fast startup.  you will need to open it in a read-only mode in all the places except one.

You can find the Speedb hive [here](https://discord.gg/5fVUUtM2cG) and (once you've registered) the link to the thread is [here](https://discord.com/channels/1001437353312796782/1086744117700198410).
Let us know if you need any assistance or additional info.